# Is there a way an ItemController can communicate with its ArrayController in ember

Tags: ember.js

I have an ArrayController whose ItemController is defined, but I want to access property of the arrayController in the itemcontroller itself. Is there a way to do so?
eg :

```
AS.AnalyticsRunEvolutionRunController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
selectedInRun: function() {

    return parentController.get('someProperty').indexOf(this.value);

}.property()
});

AS.AnalyticsRunEvolutionRunsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
itemController: 'analyticsRunEvolutionRun',
someProperty : "a,b,c"
});
```

Thanks,
Dee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `parentController` property, that is generated in a controller, when it is a itemController. So if you change your code to:

```
AS.AnalyticsRunEvolutionRunController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selectedInRun: function() {
    return this.get('parentController').get('someProperty') ...
  }.property()
});
```

Will work.

Comment: Sweet my guess turned out to be pretty close. Thanks Marcio.